# ngFor and click events

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm coming over from React into Angular for the first time and trying to get used to it. How do I execute a separate click event only for the item I want to and not every item in my JSON list?

The Logout() Service works. If I dont; use an ngFor and pass the click event directly to the template it does what it's supposed to do. But not when I pass it from a JSON in an ngFor. I suppose I can always go back to the other way, but now I am curious. Funny thing is, I added an alert() and the event is firing, just not the AuthService in the logout function...

**Template**

```
<a
   *ngFor="let usermenuitem of usermenu; let i = index"
   [routerLink]="usermenuitem.link"
   (click)="usermenuitem.goto()">
   {{usermenuitem.title}}
</a>
```

Component

```
export class AuthorisedTopNavComponent implements OnInit {

  usermenu:Object[] = [
    {
      title: 'Account',
      link: '/account',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: ()=>{},
    },
    {
      title: 'Membership',
      link: '/membership',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: ()=>{},
    },
    {
      title: 'Logout',
      link: '/',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: this.logoff,
    },
  ]

  constructor (
    public authService: AuthService
  ) {}  

  ngOnInit() {}


  logoff() {
    this.authService.logout('/');
  }

}
```

Comment: have you tried ()=> this.logoff()?

Comment: I suspect the `this` is not bound to the right context.

Comment: Try `this.logoff.bind(this)`

Comment: @OwenKelvin BOOYAA!!!! Nicely done! if you want credit, get a roper answer on this. Thanks

Comment: It's strange use [routerLink] and (click) in the same tag. I think that using `goto:()=>this.logoff()` can work, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Eliseo, that's becasue the ngFor is attached to a <a> tag that is used as a click event in some, such as the logout and as a routerlink  in other cases which only serve as a link to a page

Comment: @LOTUSMS, try then `[routerLink]="usermenuitem.link?usermenuitem.link:null" (click)="!usermenuitem.link && usermenuitem.goto()"` or use router.Navigate in the function "goto"

Comment: @Eliseo I tried to checke it out and it didn't work. Maybe with some more tweaking but it works the way I have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem analysis

The code steps and functionality is working as you have explained

> The Logout() Service works. If I dont; use an ngFor...

So what is happening? Why is the service not being called?

Lets consider the steps...

1. You call `*ngFor`

```html
<a (click)="usermenuitem.goto()" ... >
<a (click)="usermenuitem.goto()" ... >
<a (click)="usermenuitem.goto()" ... >
...
```

2. Now we breakdown `usermenuitem.goto()`. For the previous this is simply `() => {}` so they will work as expected. Our focus is on `goto: this.logoff,`

So simply we are doing something like below

```typescript
const goto = this.logoff
goto()
```

```js
class myObject {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Peter'
  }
  name = 'My Name';
  static sayName () {
    console.log('Say ' + this.name )
  }
}
console.log("Message 1 => ")
myObject.sayName()
console.log("Message 2 => ")
const p = myObject.sayName
p()
```

If you run the above code, you will see that the 1st approach works but the second does not! It throws error that `this` is not defined.

That is the problem you are facing. Your code is losing the `this` context hence not working. Other functions like `alert()` will work but any function with `this` will not work.

## Solution

To resolve this you only need to ensure you dont lose the `this` context

### Option 1

Assign a variable to store `this` e.g `that = this`. I have neve used this option in angular but works well in vanilla js

### Option 2

Simply bind `this`. This is usually the easiest option. In your situation you can simply use `this.logoff.bind(this)` and your code should work

### Option 3

Use arrow function

The is the easiest option. Simply change your `logoff` function to

```typescript
logoff = () => {
    this.authService.logout('/');
  }
```

One `gotcha` on this approach is that if you are using **TS Version 4+** you may run into issues related to the arrangement of properties, otherwise it works

Answer (score -1):

You can attach the click event on your template and pass the usermenu Object

```
   <a
   *ngFor="let usermenuitem of usermenu; let i = index"
   [routerLink]="usermenuitem.link"
   (click)="goto(usermenuitem)">
   {{usermenuitem.title}}
</a>
```

Component

```
export class AuthorisedTopNavComponent implements OnInit {

  usermenu:Object[] = [
    {
      title: 'Account',
      link: '/account',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: ()=>{},
    },
    {
      title: 'Membership',
      link: '/membership',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: ()=>{},
    },
    {
      title: 'Logout',
      link: '/',
      icon:"ua-home.svg",
      goto: this.logoff,
    },
  ]

  constructor (
    public authService: AuthService
  ) {}  

  ngOnInit() {}


  logoff() {
    this.authService.logout('/');
  }

 goto(usermenu){
  if(usermenu.title === 'logout'){
        this.logoff()
    }
 }

}
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is good practice. It's a good hack but this only works if the title is logout. If the title ever changed to signoff or logoff or something else, then the event handler has to be modified as well.